# Pyinstaller error Failed to execute script 'pyiboot01_bootstrap' due to unhandled exception! when I tried to make an app from .py file

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I got this error when I tried to make an .exe file from .py file with pyinstaller.
The full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 22, in <module>
  File "pathlib.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "urllib\parse.py", line 40, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ipaddress'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyiboot01_bootstrap.py", line 17, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyimod02_importers'
[3236] Failed to execute script 'pyiboot01_bootstrap' due to unhandled exception!
```

I used pyinstaller but I never get an error.
The command what I used:

```
pyinstaller --onefile main.py
```

Pyinstaller version: 5.8.0

Python version: 3.11.4

The python file code:

```
print('h')
```

Comment: The following link may fix your issue: [Make sure everything is packaged correctly](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/How-to-Report-Bugs#make-sure-everything-is-packaged-correctly)

Comment: It do not fix the issuse

Comment: Does that error come from running the pyinstaller command or the compiled executable? I don't really understand why it would be trying to include the ipaddress module if your code is just a print statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem. I only removed and installed again pyinstaller.

Comment: This did not work for me. I'm working from conda in a fresh environment but still got the exact same error than you. Even when reinstalling pyinstaller from forge. However switching to Python 3.11.3 instead of 3.11.5 or 4 worked :

    conda install python=3.11.3